# Como usar o gsub em mais de uma coluna

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho esse conjunto de dados:

```
dados <- data.frame(escola = c('GP','GP','TS','TS'),
                nome = c('a','b','c','d'),
                aprovado = c('sim','sim','não','não'),
                trabalha = c('sim','sim','não','não'),
                estuda_em_casa = c('sim','sim','não','não'))
```

O uso do `gsub` em uma única coluna me traz esse resultado:

```
dados <- gsub('sim',1,dados$aprovado)
dados
    escola nome aprovado trabalha estuda_em_casa
1     GP    a      sim        1            sim
2     GP    b      sim        1            sim
3     TS    c      não      não            não
4     TS    d      não      não            não
```

No entanto, a tentativa de usar o `gsub` em mais de uma coluna me dá esse resultado:

```
dados[,3:5] <- gsub('sim',1,dados[,3:5])
dados
 escola nome                  aprovado                  trabalha            estuda_em_casa
1     GP    a c("1", "1", "não", "não") c("1", "1", "não", "não") c("1", "1", "não", "não")
2     GP    b c("1", "1", "não", "não") c("1", "1", "não", "não") c("1", "1", "não", "não")
3     TS    c c("1", "1", "não", "não") c("1", "1", "não", "não") c("1", "1", "não", "não")
4     TS    d c("1", "1", "não", "não") c("1", "1", "não", "não") c("1", "1", "não", "não")
```

Porque ao usar o `gsub` em várias colunas tenho um resultado diferente do uso em uma única coluna? Como obter, em várias colunas simultaneamente, um resultado análogo ao uso do `gsub` em uma única coluna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `gsub` foi criada para trabalhar apenas com vetores. Sendo assim, devido à maneira como ela está implementada, o que a função faz é converter o data frame `dados[, 3:5]` para caracteres. Assim, o resultado final é o mesmo, sendo aplicado diretamente em `dados[, 3:5]` ou `as.character(dados[, 3:5])`:

```r
dados <- data.frame(escola = c('GP','GP','TS','TS'),
                    nome = c('a','b','c','d'),
                    aprovado = c('sim','sim','não','não'),
                    trabalha = c('sim','sim','não','não'),
                    estuda_em_casa = c('sim','sim','não','não'))

gsub('sim',1,dados[,3:5])
#> [1] "c(\"1\", \"1\", \"não\", \"não\")" "c(\"1\", \"1\", \"não\", \"não\")"
#> [3] "c(\"1\", \"1\", \"não\", \"não\")"

as.character(dados[,3:5])
#> [1] "c(\"sim\", \"sim\", \"não\", \"não\")"
#> [2] "c(\"sim\", \"sim\", \"não\", \"não\")"
#> [3] "c(\"sim\", \"sim\", \"não\", \"não\")"

gsub('sim', 1, as.character(dados[,3:5]))
#> [1] "c(\"1\", \"1\", \"não\", \"não\")" "c(\"1\", \"1\", \"não\", \"não\")"
#> [3] "c(\"1\", \"1\", \"não\", \"não\")"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Uma forma de aplicar o `gsub` em mais de uma coluna é utilizando a função `apply`:

```r
apply(dados[,3:5], 2, function(x) gsub('sim',1, x))
#>      aprovado trabalha estuda_em_casa
#> [1,] "1"      "1"      "1"           
#> [2,] "1"      "1"      "1"           
#> [3,] "não"    "não"    "não"         
#> [4,] "não"    "não"    "não"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

A função `apply` serve para aplicar uma outra função a linhas ou colunas de um data frame ou matriz. No exemplo acima, o que fiz foi:

- Usar o data frame `dados[,3:5]`
- Aplicar a função desejada nas suas colunas (por isso a opção `2`; se eu quisesse aplicar nas suas linhas, deveria ter escolhido a opção `1`)
- Criar uma função baseada no `gsub`, apenas para informar a string procurada, o que ele deveria substituir ao encontrar a string e em qual data frame aplicar a substituição, que neste caso é o `x` genérico definido em `function(x)`

Comment: Opa muito obrigado meu caro !

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.

Answer (score 3):

Se o objetivo é converter "não"/"sim" para 0/1, pode usar `ifelse` ao invés de aplicar `sub` duas vezes:

```
dados[, 3:5] <- ifelse(dados[, 3:5] == "sim", 1, 0)

dados
#>   escola nome aprovado trabalha estuda_em_casa
#> 1     GP    a        1        1              1
#> 2     GP    b        1        1              1
#> 3     TS    c        0        0              0
#> 4     TS    d        0        0              0
```

Como `ifelse` atua elemento a elemento, `apply` não é necessária. E como todas as strings são substituídas para números, as colunas já são convertidas para `numeric`:

```
str(dados)
#> 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ escola        : chr  "GP" "GP" "TS" "TS"
#>  $ nome          : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d"
#>  $ aprovado      : num  1 1 0 0
#>  $ trabalha      : num  1 1 0 0
#>  $ estuda_em_casa: num  1 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Mais uma solução, com indexação do vetor de novos valores para as colunas a processar.

A condição lógica `dados[3:5] == "sim"` é codificada como `0/1`. Somando `1` tem-se o índice para o vetor `c("não", 1)`.

```r
dados <- data.frame(escola = c('GP','GP','TS','TS'),
                    nome = c('a','b','c','d'),
                    aprovado = c('sim','sim','não','não'),
                    trabalha = c('sim','sim','não','não'),
                    estuda_em_casa = c('sim','sim','não','não'))

dados[3:5] <- c("não", 1)[1L + (dados[3:5] == "sim")]
dados
#>   escola nome aprovado trabalha estuda_em_casa
#> 1     GP    a        1        1              1
#> 2     GP    b        1        1              1
#> 3     TS    c      não      não            não
#> 4     TS    d      não      não            não
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>